# Refresh content of a page via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to load a *likes* into a div via AJAX, *every second*.

The page's name should be likes.php?p=0 on page load, likes.php?p=1 after 1 second, likes.php?p=2 afrer 2 seconds, and so on.

My code:

```
var loadLikes = function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var pageToLoad = 'likes.php' + "?p=" + counter;

    $.ajax({
        url: pageToLoad,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            counter++;
        }
    });
    console.log(pageToLoad);    
}

$(window).load(loadLikes);
setInterval(loadLikes, 1000);
```

The console (strangely, in my opinion) shows *likes.php?p=0*.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: put console.log in your success method after counter++

Comment: Interval may invoke its handler before success...

Comment: then start with 1 var counter = 1;

Comment: Each time you call function `loadLikes()`, you set `var counter = 0;`

Comment: as @A.Wolff already pointed out. u start ur function and every time u reset your Counter. And u should split ur "pagToLoad" into `data : { Key: val}` Check -> https://jsfiddle.net/vycvh1mu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put the counter variable outside function. Otherwise each time this variable will reset to `0`;

```
var counter = 0;

var loadLikes = function() {

var pageToLoad = 'likes.php' + "?p=" + counter;

$.ajax({
    url: pageToLoad,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        counter++;
    }
});
console.log(pageToLoad);    
}

$(window).load(loadLikes);
setInterval(loadLikes, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to update your `pageToLoad` also after updating counter as your initial result already stored in your variable and is not changing anymore.

```
success: function(html) {
   pageToLoad = 'likes.php' + "?p=" + ++counter;
}
```

Comment: In this case, `counter` will always be equal to 1 after string concatenation

Comment: Why? ++counter increase variable on success every time

Answer (score -1):

you are useing 'counter' variable  in your 'loadLikes' function  and every time you calling  'loadLikes' it's get 0 value .

you have to declare 'counter'  variable outside of 'loadLikes' function

```
var counter = 0;
var loadLikes = function() {

    var pageToLoad = 'likes.php' + "?p=" + counter;

    $.ajax({
        url: pageToLoad,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            counter++;
/* change your div html here 
for example : $(div).html(html);
*/
        }
    });
    console.log(pageToLoad);    
};

$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(loadLikes, 1000);
});
```